# Flash CS5 / AS3, after preloading main class constructor can't reference movieclips

Tags: actionscript-3, preload

I modified an Adobe Flash CS5 sample to create a swf with a preloader.

In my FLA I've two stopped frames:

**In the first frame** I only put this code (and a textfield showing percentage):

```
stop();

this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoading);
this.loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);

function onLoading(evt:ProgressEvent):void {
    var loaded:Number = evt.bytesLoaded / evt.bytesTotal; 
    percent_txt.text = (loaded*100).toFixed(0) + "%";
};

function onComplete(event:Event):void { 
    this.loaderInfo.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onLoading);
    this.loaderInfo.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
    gotoAndStop(2); 
};
```

**In the second frame** I:

- **exported the Main class**;
- I have all the needed graphics assets on stage;

When I test the Adobe sample (it has no main class on frame 2, only a large image) anything works fine, but when I compile the modified version I get strange errors.

**In the Main class constructor I reference three movieclips**, eg. this way: `myClip.alpha=0`, **but it seems now Flash can't see them anymore** (they are null). Why?

How can I make this preloader work?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say Main class, are you referring to a class you have set as the Document Class? If I'm following you correctly, the problem is likely that the Document Class is always instantiated on the first frame, so your instances on stage wouldn't yet exist.

It's not possible to have the Document Class wait to instantiate until later frames. You'll probably have to remove your class from the Document Class assignment in order to create your instance on frame 2. At that point, you can pass a reference to your movieclips or stage through to the constructor of your class.

Comment: HotN, in Flash Professional CS5 IDE, you can specify a frame for your Main (Document) Class.

Comment: Are you talking about the "Export classes in frame:" box in the AS3 settings? If so, that's not for the Document class. A way to test this is create a new project with an empty document class except for a public variable set in the constructor. Set the export frame to 2. On frame 1, trace the value of your variable. The results still trace out on frame one, indicating that your class has already been instantiated.

Comment: So, why they do it here? http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/workflow/the-comprehensive-guide-to-preloading-a-single-swf-file/

Comment: If you open the Main class (document class) of that tutorial, you'll see that its only responsibility is handling the preloader. In this case it's good that it automatically imports on frame 1 or it wouldn't be available for determining when the preloader completes. 

The value of setting export to frame 2 is that any assets that aren't used or imported by the document class (anything except the preloader in this case) won't need to be loaded for the document class to instantiate. So the Application class that this tutorial uses is left to be loaded after the preloader has started.